# What are StatelessWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I create a simple, basic app, like the one below, in flutter, Im creating a non explicit `StatelessWidget`?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
         body: Text('HI),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not creating a non explicit widget. So it would be neither, not Stateless nor Stateful.

The [runApp function](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/runApp.html) will just take your `MaterialApp` widget and "attach it to the screen", so you're not creating a widget along the way, but just using widgets that already exist. Your widget tree will begin at the `MaterialApp` itself.

---

Conceptually, also, I'd say that since you don't have a space to work with the state and/or variables of the widget, it could be called a `StatelessWidget`, since you can't change the state of what you built.

> Widgets describe what their view should look like **given their current configuration and state**. When a widget’s state changes, the widget rebuilds its description [...]. - from the [Flutter Widgets Intro](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro)

In your example, even though you do have `StatefulWidgets` in your app tree, you don't have a way of exposing the state of that tree, no variables, no control, no management. You're just passing other widgets to your app directly. You're actually referring one widget tree (the `MaterialApp` with its children) to the runApp function.

Answer (score 1):

although apparently we cannot interact with screen, actually inside the widget tree, we have Stateful Widget by rendering Scaffold.

[Scaffold extends StatefulWidget](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ca5411e3aa99d571ddd80b75b814718c4a94c839/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart#L950)

Answer (score 1):

As stateless widget is the one which cannot change its state or instances defined in it is final. And in your code your app state cannot be changed. So you can assume it to be a stateless widget because in flutter everything is a widget.

Answer (score 0):

Stateless widgets
There are cases where you’ll create widgets that don’t need to manage any form of internal state, this is where you’ll want to make use of the **StatelessWidget**. This widget doesn’t require any mutable state and will be used at times where other than the data that is initially passed into the object.

> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html